# How do I delete records from 1 table based on a timestamp value in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to create some php and sql for a scheduled task that would join 2 tables on a value, and delete all the records from table1 based on the unix timestamp value in table2. I have come up with the following code so far, but dont want to run it as it migh do more damage than good. Can someone help with this? Thanks in advance

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_code
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM `tbl_ctoon` WHERE tbl_code.ctoon_id=tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id AND tbl_code.code_for='C')
WHERE DATEDIFF( date(NOW( )) , FROM_UNIXTIME(expire_date)) > 3 ";
$del = new database();
$del->myquery($sql, 1);
```

So ultimately it would join the 2 tables, and delete all records from `tbl_code` where the `expire_date` in `tbl_ctoon` is greater than 3 days.

Comment: update your question add  a clear data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: `WHERE expire_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

You should join the table inside yle subquery for obtain the valid result

```
DELETE tbl_code 
FROM tbl_code
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tbl_ctoon.expire_date , tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id 
    FROM `tbl_ctoon` 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_code ON tbl_code.ctoon_id=tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id 
               AND tbl_code.code_for='C'
    ) t2 ON t2.ctoon_id =tbl_code.ctoon_id
            AND DATEDIFF( date(NOW( )) , FROM_UNIXTIME(t2. expire_date)) > 3 
WHERE tbl_code.code_for='C'
```

for test the rows involved you can

```
SELECT *  
FROM tbl_code
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tbl_ctoon.expire_date , tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id 
    FROM `tbl_ctoon` 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_code ON tbl_code.ctoon_id=tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id 
               AND tbl_code.code_for='C'
    ) t2 ON t2.ctoon_id =tbl_code.ctoon_id
            AND DATEDIFF( date(NOW( )) , FROM_UNIXTIME(t2. expire_date)) > 3 
WHERE tbl_code.code_for='C'
```

Comment: What about my other where condition?

Comment: other condition  ( AND tbl_code.code_for='C')  added

Comment: so the LEFT JOIN will only look at the id comparison, and the AND will be recognized as a separate WHERE? Thanks. I wouldnt have thought of that.

Comment: The ON condition in a JOIN is the specific where condition for the joined  table only  ..  when your on condition need  more then One clause you need  logical oerator for buil the complete clause  AND or OR  ..hope is clear  .

Comment: If I wanted to run this as a SELECT query to make sure it was pulling the right records before running it as a DELETE, would I just have to change the first line to SELECT * ?

Comment: I dont see how to add an image of the output, but it seems to be including all values in the tbl_code.code_for column, not just 'C', and it is setting the expire_date in every row to 1413176400.

Comment: answer  updated  enforcing the where condition for  WHERE tbl_code.code_for='C' hope this i what you are looking for

Comment: Its close, but I think the JOIN is multiplying it out. tbl_ctoon only has about 20000 rows. tbl_code has around 130. The select query created about 3mil rows ;)

Comment: i'm not in your data  ..  .. be sure that you join condition for the inner subquery return the right rows ..

Comment: could nbe you need  add  a condition to you join clause  ..  for  t2.ctoon_id =tbl_code.ctoon_id  ..answer  updated ..

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting I would check the query with a select.
You query could look simpler:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_code 
LEFT JOIN tbl_ctoon 
ON tbl_code.ctoon_id = tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id AND tbl_code.code_for = 'C' 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), FROM_UNIXTIME(expire_date)) > 3 AND tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id IS NOT NULL";
```

Then if your query returns the entries what you expect to delete, do the deletion:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_code 
LEFT JOIN tbl_ctoon 
ON tbl_code.ctoon_id = tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id AND tbl_code.code_for = 'C' 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), FROM_UNIXTIME(expire_date)) > 3 AND tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: That select worked perfectly! Ill try the delete later on to make sure it dropped the same records that were displayed in the select. Thank you!

Comment: One last question: when I run the select it displays the columns from both tables where the ID matches. When I run the delete, it will only delete the rows from tbl_code based on the criteria, right? Not both tables where the criteria matches

Comment: Yes, correct, it deleted from only one table. To have one table in the select you can do `SELECT tbl_code.* FROM ...`

Comment: I tried the script last night after backing up both tables (just incase), and it appears that my hosted server is running a mysql version called MariaDB, and it kicked back an error about the JOIN line. Are you familiar with that version?

Comment: According to the doc this should work https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/joining-tables-with-join-clauses/
probably you need to ask more specific question using #mariadb tag

Comment: This is the error is gives:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN tbl_ctoon 
    ON tbl_code.prz_award = tbl_ctoon.ctoon_id AND tbl_code.c' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

As the JOIN didnt work, I went a different route. I ran this and it executed fine in phpmyadmin for my database.

```
DELETE FROM tbl_code WHERE prz_award IN (SELECT ctoon_id FROM tbl_ctoon WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), FROM_UNIXTIME(expire_date)) > 120) AND tbl_code.code_for = 'C'
```